# Azure Mobile Service Single Sign on

Tags: .net, authentication, single-sign-on, azure-mobile-services

I have a problem using single sign on with azure mobile services.
I'm using the .net backend.

Whenever i call `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(provider, true);` 
so with the option enabled.
i can fill in my credentials but then the authentication screen stays white.

i get the same result whether I'm using Microsoft account or Google

When i don't pass the Boolean option, everything works fine but then i have to enter my credentials every single time

What i did:

1. I followed the tutorial on the msdn documentation : [Documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/)
2. I associated my app with a store app
3. I filled in the Google secrets in the identity tab of the mobile service
4. Did the same for the Microsoft account
5. Added my store app secret to the push tab.

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
For the Microsoft account I can use the live sdk as a workaround. But I would really like to use the same experience for google accounts.

Comment: check to see if it's the same issue as this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5083999-bf6d-4284-8d83-ef7c6e88cc5e/azure-mobile-services-authentication-broken-for-windows-phone-81?forum=azuremobile

Comment: it's not exactly the same. i did however switch to the javascript backend now and got everything working. must be a problem with the .net backend.

Comment: .Net backend with SSO is not supported right now, wasted half my week trying to get it working until I started reading latest blogs and comments.  As of today do not use .Net back end with SSO.  It will become available soonish.